# Why the שם אדנות in "אתה גבור"?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, shemos-sacred-names

The second benediction in the *amida* usually starts "אתה גבור לעולם ה׳". This is not, as far I can tell, part of a verse in *Tanach*, that prayer books should assume a certain wording or spelling based on its origin. Nonetheless, almost every modern prayer book uses the  שם אדנות here rather than the שם הויה. That is, it has the name that looks almost like ארני rather than the name that looks almost like יקוק. I assume, then, that that's accurate: the benediction really does have that name in it. Why? Why is that name used here, when it's so rarely used in general?

Comment: counterexample http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43496&st=&pgnum=132&hilite=

Comment: i don't particularly understand, but could be helpful http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%9C%22%D7%90

Comment: @msh210 I'm also wondering about many spelling questions concerning tefilot.  Recently קונה versus וקנה when tefila is a beal pe things.  The iz perhaps that orthography is a kind of mnemonic system for  cavanot of specially mechaven people

Comment: So,  for  G-d names there's a whole world of orthography and nikudim

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, in [Tefilah Yeshara](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=7190#) the shem adnut is pointed.

[Siddur Haari manuscript](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45008&st=&pgnum=115&hilite=)

[Siddur Tefilat Yesharim from Rabbi Yaacov Milisa](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6756&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=)

Somewhat that seems as an answer can be found here in [Siddur Kol Yaacov](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6755&st=&pgnum=204&hilite=), he said that a shem א-ג-ל-א, who is found in Rashe Tevot Ata Gibbor Leolam Ado-nay. The same reference to this Shem is in [Siddur Yaavets](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=22431#) (see the comment, the siddur itself does not follow the perush instructions.). In [Siddur Shaar Hashamayim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42822&st=&pgnum=191&hilite=) from HaShlah, he said sweet gvurot, and also report the shem A_G_L_A

Answer (score 1):

1) [This source](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21882&st=&pgnum=32) discusses this issue and suggests that there are different nuschaot, some with the usual form of the name, some with the more unusual form, and explains the kabbalistic basis and implications for the more unusual name.

2) Rabbi Zev Leff writes in his book *Shmoneh Esrei*: "Alternatively, *l'olam* can mean 'to the world'...(Rabbeinu Yehuda ben Yakar, in his commentary on *tefillah*). It is for this reason that God's name is written here as *alef-dalet-nun-yud*...[it] signifies God as Master of the Creation. The *alef* represents God's intrinsic existence before Creation. The final *yud* represents the unity of all of creation under God. This unity is represented by the number 10 (the *yud*'s numerical value), which is the unification of all the individual integers preceding it. And in between these two letters are the letters *dalet* and *nun*, which spell *din*, indicating the finite world of law - the laws of nature that form the boundaries and limitations of the creation."